# All hosts and services Status in the top counter and the monitoring page flapping to UNKNOWN then back to normal every few minutes

Tags: centreon-api

Eric here,

I did a fresh install of Centreon 21.10.8, with a Central and Database server.

Soon after adding hosts and services to be monitored, I noticed that the status of hosts and services go to UNKNOWN for a few seconds (about 5s to 10s) before coming back to normal. The same happens in the monitoring views: the status of monitored hosts and services go to UNKNOWN for a few seconds (about 5s to 10s) before coming back to normal. This happens at random every few minutes.

However the real status of the servers is unchanged, and checks on the command line from Central poller are OK.

[image]

--

OS: Redhat 8

Centreon Version: Centreon 21.10.8

Browser: Firefox 106.0.1, Chrome 107.0.5304.63

Steps to reproduce:

I simply open the browser on a monitoring view and observe for a few minutes.

What I have tried:

- Test Network Performance: I tried to see what is going on in the browser; I can see a lot of ajax/xhr requests from the browser to the server. The execution time of these requests in the browser does not seem to be long (100ms to 200ms for the top counter statuses and 1s to 2s for the monitoring views). I tried the same requests via curl in the cli on the Central server and I get the same execution times.
- Modifiy Refresh Settings: I tried changing the settings Administration  >  Setting >  Centreon web > Statistics page Refresh Interval from 15s to 47s and Administration  >  Setting >  Centreon web > Monitoring page Refresh Interval from 15s to 73s

I also noticed their is a javascript called vendor.2d6b7428.js that makes a large number of status requests (once every 2s) to the API right after the first status requests initiated by the Web Page itself. Found it on the server at location `/usr/share/centreon/www/static/vendor.2d6b7428.js` and in the header of the Centreon web page in a  statement:

```
<script defer="defer" scr="./static/vendor.2d6b7428.js"><script>
```

The flapping behavior persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution was found in github issue [#5609](https://github.com/centreon/centreon/issues/5609) ; the solution consisted of setting the parameter Instance timeout (*Configuration > Pollers > Broker configuration > Output > Instance timeout* OR `“instance_timeout”` in `/etc/centreon-broker/central-broker.json`) to it's default value. The value previously set by my team was 20 seconds, which caused a race condition between the freshness verification task, and the refresh interval for resource statuses, resulting in the flapping statuses.

Additional information for future readers:

- The `"instance_timeout"` (*Configuration > Pollers > Broker configuration > Output > Instance timeout*) defines a freshness time for the statuses in the GUI; passed that interval, statuses are considered expired and shown as UNKNOWN until refreshed by a routine call to the API. Default value is 300s.
- The `"monitoring_default_refresh_interval"` (*Administration > Parameters > Centreon UI > Refresh Properties*) defines an interval of time after which a query will be made to API to update the status of resources. Default value is 15s.